# The function not working after AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript function to add a wishlist , and when im not adding on the wishlist is working fine but when i add a new wishlist and trying to add something to it its not working.

```js
$('#new_wl').on("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("newWishtList").style.display = "block";
});

$('#addNewWishList').on("click", function() {
  let wishListValue = document.getElementById("new_wishlist__").value;
  $.ajax({
    url: "functions/addNewWishList.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      wishListValue: wishListValue
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var innerhtml = document.getElementById('addToWishList').innerHTML;
      document.getElementById('addToWishList').innerHTML = innerhtml + '<div class="row mb-3 wishlistclass"><div class="col-3 g-0 text-center d-flex justify-content-center ddd py-2"><i class="bi bi-heart bell-icon1 py-1 px-3"></i> </div><div class="col-8 my-auto"><h6 style="color:black" id="wishlistmm" class="ms-3">' + data + '</h6></div></div>'
      document.getElementById('new_wishlist__').value = '';

    }
  })
  document.getElementById("newWishtList").style.display = "none";
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="new_wl" style="color: #91dfa1;">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="#91dfa1" class="bi bi-plus-lg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5v5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-5h-5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h5v-5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 2Z" stroke="#91dfa1" stroke-width="2" />
  </svg> Neue Wunschliste
</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onclick="document.getElementById('newWishtList').style.display='none';" aria-label="Close">
  <svg height="24" id="Layer_1" fill="#91dfa1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="24" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <path d="M437.5,386.6L306.9,256l130.6-130.6c14.1-14.1,14.1-36.8,0-50.9c-14.1-14.1-36.8-14.1-50.9,0L256,205.1L125.4,74.5  c-14.1-14.1-36.8-14.1-50.9,0c-14.1,14.1-14.1,36.8,0,50.9L205.1,256L74.5,386.6c-14.1,14.1-14.1,36.8,0,50.9  c14.1,14.1,36.8,14.1,50.9,0L256,306.9l130.6,130.6c14.1,14.1,36.8,14.1,50.9,0C451.5,423.4,451.5,400.6,437.5,386.6z"></path>
  </svg>
</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body text-center" id="newWishtList" style="display: none;">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text " class="form-control" name="" id="new_wishlist__" style="display:block; margin-left: -1px; border: none;border-radius: 0; outline: 0; border-bottom: solid 1px #91dfa1;opacity: 0.8;" />
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <span>
        <button class="btn mt-2" id="addNewWishList" style="font-size:20px;color:#91dfa1">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="#91dfa1" class="bi bi-plus-lg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5v5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-5h-5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h5v-5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 2Z" stroke="#91dfa1" stroke-width="2" />
          </svg>
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check the browser console for errors? How exactly does the code fail?

Comment: "its not working" - could explain in detail what works and doesn't work. What are the symptoms and what is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Also all this code `var innerhtml = document.getElementById('addToWishList').innerHTML;
      document.getElementById('addToWishList').innerHTML = innerhtml +`  can be replaced by `document.getElementById('addToWishList').innerHTML +=`

Comment: @phuzi At first all the code works when i enter the page, after a new wishlist been added, I return all the wishlists with Ajax calls, but after I return them my javascript functions thats been there doesnt work anymore.

Comment: check "promise .js" for waiting the ajax exécution

Comment: @WilliamLanglois can you explain that in more details ?

Comment: like here : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise you make a promise => you call your ajax methode => wait the exécution and execute others lines